# applescripts to open all sites in bookmark folder in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

New to applescripts trying to open all sites of a bookmark folder in a new Chrome window using applescripts.

This is what I have so far

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    make new (window)
    activate "bookmark bar"
    open bookmark folder "Start My Day" of bookmark folder "My Day" of "bookmark bar"
end tell
```

Comment: you do know that there is a menu option to open all bookmarks right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good start...

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    set myBMFolder to bookmark folder "Start My Day" of bookmark folder "My Day" of bookmark folder "Bookmarks Bar"
    set bmURLs to URL of bookmark items of myBMFolder
    repeat with aUrl in bmURLs
        open location aUrl
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for this!! It worked great. My next phase is to have applescripts sign me in once the sights are open. I know the Text of the button's that need to be clicked just wondering what is the best way to get this moving. Is it through System events or Java? Thanks for your Help on this

Comment: Javascript is best for that.

Comment: if the Text of the button is "Log in" in Chrome what would be the best Java script to execute the click of that button?Tell application "google chrome"
 Tell Active Tab
  set myUrl to URL of URL (Log in) 
  Tell application "system Events"
  click myUrl
 end Tell
End Tell